# Svelte, Netlify (deploy failed)

Tags: javascript, deployment, svelte, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a svelte app into netlify. I got a deployment failed message in the logs.

```
[!] Error: Could not load /opt/build/repo/src/components/itemCard.svelte 
(imported by src/Product/Categories.svelte): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/opt/build/repo/src/components/itemCard.svelte'
9:59:41 PM: Error: Could not load /opt/build/repo/src/components/itemCard.svelte
(imported by src/Product/Categories.svelte): ENOENT: no such file or directory,
open '/opt/build/repo/src/components/itemCard.svelte'
```

I thought the problem with the path. Therefore, I've used different path techniques
such as, `./../` or `src` but it doesn't work.
note: the code is working fine in the local.

Any help, please?

Comment: Maybe you're developing with Windows but Netlify runs on Linux and thus is case sensitive while Windows isn't? So make sure your file paths exactly match the actual files'.

Comment: Thanks, but my OS environment is mac os which is also case sensitive.

Comment: Well, not really. I'd check it.